# Mitmproxy doesn't capture http request even after installing ssl certificates and setting up systemwide proxy

Tags: ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04, http-proxy, mitmproxy

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to cature http/https requests using mitmproxy

I was able to capture http/https requests sent by firefox browser by installing certificates on the browser and setting up browser proxy settings

But I want to capture every http/https request which are sent by any software in my computer.

So I installed system wide ssl certificate for mitmproxy and changed network proxy settings of the system. But now Mitmproxy doesn't capture any request.

```
network proxy settigns (manual)
127.0.0.1(localhost)  port 4001

mitmproxy listening on
127.0.0.1(localhost)  port 4001
```

what should I do? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Setting a proxy in the system settings does not necessarily means that it is used by all programs. A lot of programs just use their own settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with mitmproxy running as a transparent proxy. See their [documentation](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/) for how this is configured; your proxy box will need to be configured as the gateway for your testing box.